# Не работает обработчик роута

Tags: golang

НАпсиал такой роутер

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.HandleFunc("/home/", ShowForms) //ShowFroms помечается как ошибка.
```

И такую функцию обработки

```
func ShowForms(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    templ, _ := template.ParseFiles("../static/main.tmpl.html")
    templ.Execute(w, nil)
    log.Println("Try show ----->", templ.Name())
}
```

Как и описано в [репозитории разработчика mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux#examples).

Но у меня ShowForms помечается как ошибка.(комментарий добавил)

В связи с чем это происходит? Ведь ShowForms это HandleFunc как и требует пакет mux

Вот сама ошибка

```
cannot use ShowForms (value of type func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)) as func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) value in argument to router.HandleFunc
```

Comment: Я [проверил ваш код](https://pastebin.com/LiGRifpP) - компилируется и запускается.  Какой пакет у вас используется как `http`? Должен быть `"net/http"`. И проверьте, пожалуйста, ваш пост: потеряна открывающая `{` в примере ShowForms

Comment: @PakUula Да, используется именно net/http((

Comment: все верно. покажите весь код, если сможете

Comment: @SeniorPomidor  [Здесь](https://github.com/udonetsm/dbservice) . 
Но уже разобрался. Я очень непредусмотрительно свой пакет с хэндлерами назвал http и, видимо, при использовании функций из /net/http происходил какой-то конфликт) . Думаю это и вызвало проблему. Переименовал пакет, пересобрал модуль и все  стало работать)

Answer (score 0):

Удалил файлы go.mod, go sum, и сделал:

```
go mod init <mod_name>
go mod tidy
```

Теперь все работает